# Connecting two lines at the end using derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I have the sine curve:
$f(x)=2.75461\sin⁡(0.456984(x+1.38513))+6.5671$

The curve must smoothly connect with an exponential curve around the point $(8.297,3.813)$.

How would I find the equation for the exponential function using derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

We need to solve a system of simultaneous equations

Let $g(x) = A e^{r x}$

Then in order for the curve $f$ to smoothly connect with $g$ we must have

$f(x) = g(x) = 3.813 = A e^{8.297 r}$
$f'(x) = g'(x) = -0.907097 = r A e^{r x} = r A e^{8.297 r}$
at $x = 8.297$.

Hence $r = -0.237896$ and we can similarly solve for $A$.